# Union returns two rows if data is different, one if it's the same! Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Taking the following statement:

```
select count( 1 ) as cnt from tbl where val= 1 
union
select count( 1 ) as cnt from tbl where val = 0
```

If the two selects return the same value the result is a single row with that value. If the selects return different values the result is two rows with the two values. Why?

I am trying to find the total count of rows using:

```
select sum (cnt) from
(
    select count( 1 ) as cnt from tbl where value = 1
    union
    select count( 1 ) as cnt from tbl where value = 0
) as tbl2
```

which works as expected if the counts are different but gives half the value if the counts are the same...

(PS : More interested in why sql behaves this way than in a solution)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior is by design. You should use `UNION ALL` to achieve the behavior you want. Basically, `UNION` performs a set union operation, removing the duplicates in the set.

http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/SQL/SQLtip5.asp

Comment: @Mherdad, why did they design it like that?

Comment: @Geoffrey, in the case of a `select count` it seems strange, but for a `select firstname, lastname from persons` it makes sense to return each person just once.

Comment: @Geoffrey: I didn't exist at the time they designed SQL, but I can guess: relational calculus is based on set theory and SQL is basically a syntax for expressing relational calculus queries. Basically, `union`, is a counterpart to `intersect`, both of which are set theoretic operations. It made sense for designers to keep them as such and introduce a separate query operator, `union all` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

the main difference between union and union all is that union does a distinct over all fields returned. Where union all just returns and joins the various result sets